# Focus TreeViewItem (with binding and virtualization)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, treeview

I have this TreeView control:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" Width="300" ItemsSource="{Binding TvMview.FirstNodes}"
              VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SecondNodes}">
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ThirdNodes}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeaderText}" Background="Red"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text=">>> " Background="Green"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeaderText}" Background="blue"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded}" />
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TreeView>
```

Binded to:

```
public class ModelView
{
    public TreeViewModelView TvMview { get; set; } = new TreeViewModelView();
}

public class TreeViewModelView
{
    public ObservableCollection<FirstNode> FirstNodes { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<FirstNode>();
}

public class FirstNode : TreeItem
{
    public ObservableCollection<SecondNode> SecondNodes { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<SecondNode>();
    public string HeaderText { get; set; }
}

public class SecondNode : TreeItem
{
    public ObservableCollection<ThirdNode> ThirdNodes { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ThirdNode>(); 
    public string HeaderText { get; set; }
}

public class ThirdNode 
{
    public string HeaderText { get; set; }
}

public class TreeItem
{
    public bool IsExpanded { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

And everything is working as expected. But... I want to implement seach:

```
foreach (var firstNode in Mview.TvMview.FirstNodes)
        {
            if (firstNode.HeaderText.Contains(textBox.Text))
            {
                firstNode.IsExpanded = true;
                firstNode.IsSelected = true;
                TreeViewItem tvItem = (TreeViewItem)treeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(firstNode);
                tvItem?.Focus();
                return;
            }
        }
```

The right node is expanded but tvItem is always null. I read somewhere sometime that ContainerFromItem doesn't likes virtualization...

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: ContainerFromItem will not work until the item has been created.  Try adding VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" to your treeview.  Are your viewmodels right?  Did you implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented in the TreeItem base class. And sure... removing virtualization fixes the issue, but, thats the whole point...  For instance, adding 30.000 items to the TreeView without virutalization: 180 secs. with virtualization: 1 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved this issue implementing a Focus() method in the TreeItem base class. So, base class look like this:

```
public class TreeItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _IsExpanded;
    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get { return _IsExpanded; }
        set { _IsExpanded = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsExpanded"); }
    }

    private bool _IsSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _IsSelected; }
        set { _IsSelected = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected"); }
    }        

    public void Focus(TreeView tView)
    {
        TreeViewItem tvItem = (TreeViewItem)tView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(this);
        tvItem?.Focus();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
if (firstNode.HeaderText.Contains(textBox.Text))
{
    firstNode.IsExpanded = true;
    firstNode.IsSelected = true;
    firstMatch.Focus();
}
```